# How to click on button and pop up alert message using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unable to get the alert message to pop up.  I have all the other jQuery code working, so I know I linked the library correctly.  Could it be where I put it in the document that matters?

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="cancelForm">Cancel</button>
```

jQuery:

```
   $(".cancelForm").submit(function(){
     alert('Are you sure you want to cancel?');
   });
```

UPDATE: Still couldn't get it to work.  I wil try relabeling later.  Thanks for the tips.

```
$(".cancelForm").on('click', function(){
alert('Are you sure you want to cancel?');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an on click, not on submit.

```
$(".cancelForm").click(function()
```

Also - call your button's class something else (right now, it's "cancelForm", which implies that it's a form, which is confusing you - and will likely confuse developers that need to maintain the code after you.

Also - use a jquery dialog to show a message, not an alert().

Answer (score 0):

The button type would need to be "submit" for this javascript to work. otherwise you would need to have an onclick event handler for the button.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but putting the code within the document.ready section.  Thank you for our help

Comment: Yes, the $('.cancelform')... makes _changes_ to your button so the button must exist before making them, that said, you need to wait until the button has been loaded into the document :)